# What is my random access iterator missing?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
  static Node mNode;
};  
        
Node Node::mNode;
    
struct DeepNodeRange {};
    
class DeepNodeIter
{ 
public:
  using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
  using value_type = Node*;
  using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
      
  DeepNodeIter() = default;
      
  DeepNodeIter(DeepNodeRange& deepNodeRange, bool end = false) :
    mDeepNodeRange(&deepNodeRange), mIdx(0), mEnd(end) {}
        
  Node* operator[](int idx) const { return &Node::mNode; }
    
  Node* operator*() const { return &Node::mNode; }
    
  Node* operator->() { return &Node::mNode; }
      
  DeepNodeIter& operator++()
  {
    mIdx++;
    mEnd = (mIdx > 10);
      
    return *this; 
  }

  DeepNodeIter operator++([[maybe_unused]] int val)
  {
    auto tmp(*this);
    operator++();

    return tmp;
  }

  DeepNodeIter& operator--()
  {
    mIdx--;
    mEnd = (mIdx > 10);

    return *this;
  }

  DeepNodeIter operator--([[maybe_unused]] int val)
  {
    auto tmp(*this);
    operator--();

    return tmp;
  }

  DeepNodeIter& operator+=(int val)
  {
    mIdx += val;
    mEnd = (mIdx > 10);

    return *this;
  }

  DeepNodeIter& operator-=(int val)
  {
    mIdx -= val;
    mEnd = (mIdx > 10);

    return *this;
  }

  int operator+(const DeepNodeIter& other) const
  {
    return mIdx + other.mIdx;
  }

  int operator-(const DeepNodeIter& other) const
  {
    return mIdx - other.mIdx;
  }

  DeepNodeIter operator+(int val) const
  {
    auto tmp(*this);
    tmp.mIdx += val;
    return tmp;
  }

  DeepNodeIter operator-(int val) const
  {
    auto tmp(*this);
    tmp.mIdx -= val;
    return tmp;
  }

  bool operator==(const DeepNodeIter& iter) const { return iter.mEnd == mEnd; }

  bool operator!=(const DeepNodeIter& iter) const { return iter.mEnd != mEnd; }

  bool operator<(const DeepNodeIter& iter) const { return iter.mIdx < mIdx; }

  bool operator<=(const DeepNodeIter& iter) const { return iter.mIdx <= mIdx; }

  bool operator>(const DeepNodeIter& iter) const { return iter.mIdx > mIdx; }

  bool operator>=(const DeepNodeIter& iter) const { return iter.mIdx >= mIdx; }

protected:
  DeepNodeRange* mDeepNodeRange;

  int mIdx;

  bool mEnd;
};

static_assert(std::random_access_iterator<DeepNodeIter>);

int main() {
  DeepNodeRange deepNodeRange;

  DeepNodeIter i(deepNodeRange);
  DeepNodeIter j(deepNodeRange);
  std::cout << (i - j) << std::endl;
}
```

It results in the following compile error:

```
b.cpp:122:20: error: static assertion failed
  122 | static_assert(std::random_access_iterator<DeepNodeIter>);
      |               ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
b.cpp:122:20: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:71,
                 from include/c++/11.1.0/iterator:61,
                 from b.cpp:1:
include/c++/11.1.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:625:13:   required for the satisfaction of 'sized_sentinel_for<_Iter, _Iter>' [with _Iter = DeepNodeIter]
include/c++/11.1.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:627:8:   in requirements with 'const _Iter& __i', 'const _Sent& __s' [with _Sent = DeepNodeIter; _Iter = DeepNode
include/c++/11.1.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:629:13: note: the required expression '(__s - __i)' is invalid
  629 |       { __s - __i } -> same_as<iter_difference_t<_Iter>>;
      |         ~~~~^~~~~
include/c++/11.1.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:630:13: note: the required expression '(__i - __s)' is invalid
  630 |       { __i - __s } -> same_as<iter_difference_t<_Iter>>;
      |         ~~~~^~~~~
cc1plus: note: set '-fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=' to at least 2 for more detail
```

I checked and my iterator fulfills all the requires [for LegacyRandomIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator). What am I missing here?

Comment: *note: set '-fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=' to at least 2 for more detail*

Comment: Not a c++ wizard - what is that static_assert trying to assert? I expected to see a constexpr boolean

Comment: Your `operator-()` returns `int`.   It needs to return `DeepNodeIter::difference_type` (which you have specified as being `std::ptrdiff_t`).    Additionally (although it's not showing for you yet, probably because your test code is incomplete) I suspect you also need to ensure addition works right  (`an_iter + n` and `n + an_iter` need to return the same thing).

Comment: @pm100, `std::random_access_iterator` is a concept. The static assertion is ensuring that `DeepNodeIter` models that concept.

Comment: @chris ty for the explanation

Comment: "*I checked and my iterator fulfills all the requires for LegacyRandomIterator.*" In fact, [not really](https://godbolt.org/z/fona6sxM7).

Answer (score 1):

Two problems: Your `operator-` does not return `difference_type` and your `operator+` signature is all wrong. Regarding the latter, the two types being added must be your iterator and its `difference_type`, in either order, implying that it must necessarily be a pair of (possibly `friend`) free functions.

```
friend DeepNodeIter operator+(difference_type n, DeepNodeIter it)
{
    return it += n;
}

friend DeepNodeIter operator+(DeepNodeIter it, difference_type n)
{
    return it += n;
}

difference_type operator-(const DeepNodeIter& other) const
{
    return mIdx - other.mIdx;
}
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://godbolt.org/z/cv8G3bzbv)</kbd>

Also while it won't make the concept fail, the concept assumes that `operator[]` also takes `difference_type`.

Comment: What should operator[] take? can you update the link with your suggestion?

Comment: It's part of the random_access_iterator spec. What differentiates it from a forward iterator.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator

Comment: @dromodel : Fair enough, good point! Well, the very page you linked to says directly that its argument should be the iterator's `difference_type`, so there you go. The only reason the concept doesn't fail for your implementation is because concepts can check for exact return types but only for convertible argument types. (N.b. the documentation you should actually be looking at is [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/random_access_iterator), though, since that's the concept you're actually trying to satisfy.)

Answer (score 0):

The addition and subtraction operators need to use 'difference_type' and alternative addition and subtraction operator needed to be defined outside of the class definition because one of the requirements for the concept is that their arguments can be switched around.

Here's the fixed version of your code:

```
    #include <iterator>
    #include <iostream>
    
    struct Node {
      static Node mNode;
    };  
            
    Node Node::mNode;
        
    struct DeepNodeRange {};
        
    class DeepNodeIter
    { 
    public:
      using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
      using value_type = Node*;
      using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
          
      DeepNodeIter() = default;
          
      DeepNodeIter(DeepNodeRange& deepNodeRange, bool end = false) :
        mDeepNodeRange(&deepNodeRange), mIdx(0), mEnd(end) {}
            
      Node* operator[](int idx) const { return &Node::mNode; }
        
      Node* operator*() const { return &Node::mNode; }
        
      Node* operator->() { return &Node::mNode; }
          
      DeepNodeIter& operator++()
      {
        mIdx++;
        mEnd = (mIdx > 10);
          
        return *this; 
      }
    
      DeepNodeIter operator++([[maybe_unused]] int val)
      {
        auto tmp(*this);
        operator++();
    
        return tmp;
      }
    
      DeepNodeIter& operator--()
      {
        mIdx--;
        mEnd = (mIdx > 10);
    
        return *this;
      }
    
      DeepNodeIter operator--([[maybe_unused]] int val)
      {
        auto tmp(*this);
        operator--();
    
        return tmp;
      }
    
      DeepNodeIter& operator+=(difference_type val)
      {
        mIdx += val;
        mEnd = (mIdx > 10);
    
        return *this;
      }
    
      DeepNodeIter& operator-=(difference_type val)
      {
        mIdx -= val;
        mEnd = (mIdx > 10);
    
        return *this;
      }
    
      difference_type operator+(const DeepNodeIter& other) const
      {
        return mIdx + other.mIdx;
      }
    
      difference_type operator-(const DeepNodeIter& other) const
      {
        return mIdx - other.mIdx;
      }
    
      DeepNodeIter operator+(difference_type val) const
      {
        auto tmp(*this);
        tmp.mIdx += val;
        return tmp;
      }
    
      DeepNodeIter operator-(difference_type val) const
      {
        auto tmp(*this);
        tmp.mIdx -= val;
        return tmp;
      }
    
      bool operator==(const DeepNodeIter& iter) const { return iter.mEnd == mEnd; }
    
      bool operator!=(const DeepNodeIter& iter) const { return iter.mEnd != mEnd; }
    
      bool operator<(const DeepNodeIter& iter) const { return iter.mIdx < mIdx; }
    
      bool operator<=(const DeepNodeIter& iter) const { return iter.mIdx <= mIdx; }
    
      bool operator>(const DeepNodeIter& iter) const { return iter.mIdx > mIdx; }

  bool operator>=(const DeepNodeIter& iter) const { return iter.mIdx >= mIdx; }

protected:
  DeepNodeRange* mDeepNodeRange;

  int mIdx;

  bool mEnd;
};

DeepNodeIter operator+(DeepNodeIter::difference_type val, DeepNodeIter const& self)
{
  return self + val;
}

DeepNodeIter operator-(DeepNodeIter::difference_type val, DeepNodeIter const& self)
{
  return self + val;
}

static_assert(std::random_access_iterator<DeepNodeIter>);

int main() {
  DeepNodeRange deepNodeRange;

  DeepNodeIter i(deepNodeRange);
  DeepNodeIter j(deepNodeRange);
  std::cout << (i - j) << std::endl;
}
```